# Mod Rewrite and 404 Error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

At the moment the users of my website can access files with the following url-schema:
`http://www.example.com/dwl/download.php?file=/files/index.rar`

Now i want that they can access it with the following schema:
`http://www.example.com/dwl/content/files/index.rar`

The download.php file is within the dwl directory.
I tried the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ download.php?file=$1 [L]
```

But when i try it, i get a 404-Error.
Can anybody please help me to write the correct .htaccess-Entry?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from `http://www.example.com/dwl/download.php?file=/files/index.rar` to `http://www.example.com/dwl/content/files/index.rar`, you need this:

```
RewriteRule ^/dwl/download.php?file=/(.*) /dwl/content/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No, i want to redirect from http://www.example.com/dwl/download.php?file=/files/index.rar to http://www.example.com/dwl/content/files/index.rar

Comment: why? people try to make clean urls and if you enter `example.com/dwl/content/files/index.rar` `.htaccess` shows the content of `example.com/dwl/content/files/index.rar`

Comment: @user4035 - should not be `RewriteRule ^/dwl/content/(.*)$ /dwl/download.php?file=/$1 [L]` ?

Comment: @imsiso Sorry, I misunderstood the question. Yes, if he wants to access the file directly, when the users try to access it via download.php, it should be reversed.

Comment: It won't work because `RewriteRule` doesn't match a query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you have to use is the following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/dwl/content(/files/[^/]*)$ /dwl/download.php?file=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT/dwl` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dwl/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+dwl/download\.php\?file=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ content/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^content/(.+)$ download.php?file=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```